# $A+B=C$. Can $A$ be expressed in terms of $A^2$, $C$ and $C^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Suppose $$A + B = C$$ $$A\ge0$$ $$B\ge0$$

I know values for the following $A^2$, $C$ and $C^2$.

Is there any way to write an equation for $A$ (or $B$ or $B^2$) in terms of $A^2$, $C$ and $C^2$ $\text{WITHOUT}$ using square roots?

Or are there simply not enough constraints to do so?

Comment: You used the tag linear-algebra. Are $A,B,C$ matrices? And are $A,B$ positive semi-definite, or do they have non-negative entries?

Comment: If you happen to know that $A$ is positive semidefinite, then there's no good reason to avoid square roots.

Comment: Of course, we seem to have $C \geq A$ and $C \geq B$, which may be useful.

Comment: A, B and C are non-negative numbers.  The necessity to avoid square roots is that over this domain the integral of the square root is discontinuous.

Comment: Is it possible to break the domain into regions over which the square root is continuous?

Comment: If there was a way to do it without square roots, it would still work even if $A$ was negative, right? So it should be able to solve it if $A=-1$, $C=1$, $C^2=1$. But in this case, $A$ is imaginary, and you can't get to imaginary numbers without square roots or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A,B\ge0$ we have $C=A+B \implies C\ge A\text{ and }C\ge B$. Then we can write

$A=C \sin\alpha,\qquad\alpha\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}) \tag{1}$

and then

$$\frac{A^2}{C^2}=\sin^2\alpha=\frac{1-\cos2\alpha}{2} \implies \cos2\alpha=1-2\frac{A^2}{C^2},\qquad 2\alpha\in[0,\pi) \tag{2}$$

so you can solve uniquely for $\alpha$ as cosine is injective on the domain $[0,\pi)$. Then equation (1) gives the value of $A$.

As a single formula:

$$A=C\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\arccos\left(1-2\frac{A^2}{C^2}\right)\right) \tag{3}$$

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but if you **really** want to avoid square roots $\dots$

Comment: Marconius - thank you for the input.  Unfortunately that bad boy formula for A can't be integrated.  Thanks for your help though.